# Unique style for each dialog header in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to set different header color for each dialog.
I have a few dialogs like this:

```
<p:dialog header="dilog name" widgetVar="inputDialog" id="inputDlg" 
          modal="true" resizable="false" class="topRed"
          onHide="PF('inputDialogTabViewWidget').select(0)">  ...      
</p:dialog>
```

And I have this style:

```
.ui-widget-header .topRed { 
    border: 1px solid #e78f08;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow',sans-serif;
    background:  url(../img/title-bg3.png) repeat-x !important;
    font-weight: bold;
 }
```

Which is not working, but when I override bace style all works fine. Css below sets one style for all dialog.

```
.ui-widget-header { 
    border: 1px solid #e78f08;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow',sans-serif;
    background:  url(../img/title-bg3.png) repeat-x !important;
    font-weight: bold; 
}
```

Comment: are you sure `.ui-widget-header .topRed` is good? Shouldn't it be `.topRed .ui-widget-header ` or something like that? Check with a browser developer tool... Easy to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap style as .top-red .ui-widget-header